# Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant

Im on Ubuntu 12.04 and my Vagranfile looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.box = "base"
config.vm.box_url = "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/precise/current/precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"

config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080

config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
  puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
  puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
  puppet.manifest_file  = "init.pp"
  puppet.options="--verbose --debug"
end

end
```

This was supposed to be running fine, the same configuration works OK in my macbook.
Im using Vagrant 1.3.5 a VirtualBox  4.1.12 (but before I tried with 4.2.18)

I dont know how to fix this, I've been stuck for days now. Any help will be great.

Comment: what types of errors are you seeing? What are you stuck on/what does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you have a proper version of GuestAdditions. Or just use [vagrant-vbguest plugin](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) that will check and install it for you. In fact, it is must have plugin if you are using VirtualBox.
2. Try to increase `config.ssh.timeout` (default: 5 min.)

This is not really an answer, rather possible ways of solving. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2163) on vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Vagrant bug that should be [fixed](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/4696/files) in next version.

So far just make sure that the `~/vagrant.d/insecure_private_key` file is owned by the same user that starts Vagrant, and has permissions `600`, this should help.